# AGILETOOLKIT :: js()->..->execute() must be used in response to form submission or AJAX operation only

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, atk4

I am getting this error when i do form submit.

[image: Application Error]

here is my code:
`View`

```
 class View_Tabs_Activities extends View {
    function init() {
    parent::init();

    $f = $this->add('Form', null, 'PostForm');
    $f->setModel('Post');
    $f->addSubmit();
}
function defaultTemplate() {
    return array('view/tabs/activities');
}
}
```

`HTML`

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="shareTab">
            <div class="share">
                <?$PostForm?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is something that i found by checking the console:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that there were 2 jQuery files included in the same html page that is why `$.atk4` was `undefined`. I removed the 2nd one and its working fine now.